# My Javascript is not executing to change backgroundColor of Box to blue. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").backgroundColor="blue";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button id="button2">Blue</button>
    <button id="button3">Fade</button>
    <button id="button4">Reset</button>

    

</body>
</html>
```

When I `click` the button2 it should turn the box to blue from orange. Is my link to the javascript wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access `backgroundColor`you need to access `style` property of the element, as it is nested under it.

So you need to do `document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor="blue";`

See the code below:

```js
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor="blue";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button id="button2">Blue</button>
    <button id="button3">Fade</button>
    <button id="button4">Reset</button>

    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I updated the code but the box still won't change color when I click the "blue" button. I am using visual studio code. I see that it works on here when i run code snippet. My javascript file is also in the same location as my html file. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: @user2763557 yiu have corrected `.style.backgroundColor="blue"` right?

Comment: Yes updated it exactly   document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor="blue";
});

Comment: @user2763557 your JS code should be placed after html code. Just above closing body tag. Check that once.

Comment: so not in a separate file?

Comment: If it is in a separate file then the `<script src="..."` tag should be just above closing body tag.

Comment: woah ok, so i put the script tags just above closing body tag and now it works! is this where i always link external javascript file? I was under the impression it should always be in between the head tags.

Comment: @user2763557 No JS is best placed there. CSS is what comes in between head tags. Do upvote and mark the answer correct :)